# xbindkeys and xdotool does not work for Enter or Return

Tags: command-line, 18.04, keyboard, xdotool, xbindkeys

I try to bind some keys to other keys via `xdotool` commands in `.xbindkeysrc`. Everything works fine but I cannot simulate `Enter` by any key. Neither of the following commands work.

```
"xdotool key KP_Enter"
  q

"xdotool key Return"
  q
```

even

```
"xdotool key KP_Enter"
  KP_Enter
```

does not work.

The following command

```
"xdotool key Return;sleep 1;xdotool key BackSpace"
  KP_Add
```

ignores `Return` and trigger `BackSpace` after 1 second.

However,

```
"xdotool key Return"
  b:8
```

works. It seems I can bind the mouse to `Return`, but NOT a key.

Comment: By "It seems I can bind the mouse to Return, but NOT a key." do you mean you want to bind a single key to generate *Return*? In Kubuntu 18.04, I can successfully bind the combination of `Super+'` to `xdotool key Return`.